# an isomorphism to product ring $\mathbb{C}\times \mathbb{C}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Examine whether there is a polynomial $f(X)\in \mathbb{R}[X]$ such that $\frac{\mathbb{R}[X]}{(f(X))}$ is isomorphic to the product ring $\mathbb{C}\times \mathbb{C}$.

I have found a particular example if the polynomial ring would be of two variable, e.g. $\frac{\mathbb{R}[X,Y]}{(X^2+1,Y^2+1)}$ which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}\times \mathbb{C}$, or if we allow the ring over $\mathbb{C}$, e.g. $\frac{\mathbb{C}[X]}{X^2+1}$. I think it is not possible to find such $f$ over $\mathbb{R}[X]$ but I am unable to provide a justification there. All I have figured out that $\mathbb{C}\times \mathbb{C}$ is neither an integral domain nor a field, hence $(f(X))$ is neither prime nor maximal ideal. So $f(X)$ has to be a reducible polynomial over $\mathbb{R}[X]$, if it exists. Can we conclude something from here?

Comment: As $\Bbb C\times\Bbb C$ has dimension four over $\Bbb R$, you would need a degree four polynomial.

Comment: I have just tried $\frac{\mathbb{R}[X]}{(X^4-1)}$ but this is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: $X^4-1=(X-1)(X+1)(X^2+1)$ has two real roots and two imaginary roots.

Comment: I think $\frac{\mathbb{R}[X]}{X^4+X^2+1}$ fulfills the criterion. Am I correct?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: something similar $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}\cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ can happen over polynomial rings.

Note that $(x^2+1)^2$ won't work, similar to $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}\not\cong\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. However, unlike with $\mathbb{Z}$, it is possible to quotient $\mathbb{R}[x]$ by different polynomials and get the same quotient ring $\mathbb{C}$.

(If you're familiar with the general form of the Chinese Remainder Theorem for rings, good.)

Answer (score 2):

$$\mathbb R[X]/\left<(X^2+1)(X^2+2)\right>\stackrel{\mathrm{CRT}}\simeq\mathbb R[X]/\left<(X^2+1)\right>\times\mathbb R[X]/\left<(X^2+2)\right>\simeq\mathbb C\times\mathbb C$$